# PHP Laravel 5.5 collections flatten and keep the integer keys?

Tags: php, laravel, flatten, collect

I have the following array :

```
$array = [
    '2' => ['3' => ['56' => '2'], '6' => ['48' => '2']],
    '4' => ['4' => ['433' => '2', '140' => '2'], '8' => ['421' => '2', '140' => '2']],
    '5' => ['5' => ['88' => '4', '87' => '2']]
];
```

The following code (flattening) should return it by preserving keys, but it doesnt?

```
collect($array)->flatten(1);
```

should give me

```
[
    '3' => ['56' => '2'],
    '6' => ['48' => '2'],
    '4' => ['433' => '2', '140' => '2'],
    '8' => ['421' => '2', '140' => '2'],
    '5' => ['88' => '4', '87' => '2']
]
```

However it loses the keys, and just gives array results :/
Am I using it wrong? How should I flatten and preserve keys?

Comment: I don't believe `flatten` supports maintaining keys - how would you expect it to work if the keys in a lower level weren't unique?

Comment: OK, thanks. It makes sense in retrospect why flatten wouldn't keep the keys.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

An elegant solution is to use the [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-mapwithkeys) method. This will flatten your array and keep the keys:

```
collect($array)->mapWithKeys(function($a) {
    return $a;
});
```

> The `mapWithKeys` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback should return an associative array containing a single key / value pair

Comment: It can be more elegant/shorter now with arrow function. Works only with PHP 7.4 and above
`collect($array)->mapWithKeys(fn($a) => $a);`

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Since map doesn't flatten, it's unintuitive that map with keys would.

Comment: nice working. thanks

Comment: same can be achieved with `collect($array)->flatMap(fn ($v) => $v)` which has the added bonus of having the word `flat` for a more expressive statement, although the `fn ($v) => $v` part ruins it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `flatten()` here. I don't have an elegant solution, but I've tested this and it works perfectly for your array:

```
foreach ($array as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        $newArray[$key] = $item;
    }
}

dd($newArray);
```

Comment: This did work. Trying to avoid foreach'es, but it did. thanks.